# Pushing values into Ms Word docx format document with Mustache markup?

Tags: javascript, docx

I have seen a script that allow mustache styled markup in a docx to be populated from code  I cannot find such again. Does anyone know of such a script.

Comment: https://github.com/edi9999/docxgenjs

Comment: https://github.com/wrklst/docxmustache does this in a php class with actual mustache syntax (implements the official php mustache class)

Answer (score 0):

Yep, [docxgenjs](https://github.com/edi9999/docxgenjs) does exactly that (I'm it's creator).

Here's a simple demo working on Chrome and Firefox: http://javascript-ninja.fr/docxgenjs/examples/demo.html

You can use it client-side on new browsers (not IE, sadly), or on server-side with node: https://github.com/edi9999/docxgenjs#node-installation-and-usage